# ng-model not registering upon form submission

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, user-interface

I am playing around with ng-if in my form. I want the user to be able to select a color (which triggers a function by ng-change), then wants to switch colors, selects a different color (which triggers a different function), and depending on whether the switch happens, choose from different resulting dropdown menus.

HTML

```
<form name = "myForm" ng-submit = "submit()">

    <label> Select color </label>
    <select ng-model="myColor" ng-change = "setColorSelection()" class="form-control" 
        ng-options = "color as color for color in colors" required>
    </select>
    <br>

    <label> Switch colors? </label> <br>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="switchColors" value = "yes" >Yes</input>
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type= "radio" ng-model = "switchColors" value = "no" >No</input>
    </label>
    <br>

    <div ng-show = "switchColors == 'yes'">
        <label> Which color will you switch to? </label>
        <select ng-model="myColorSwitched" ng-change = "setColorSelectionSwitched()" class="form-control" 
            ng-options = "color as color for color in colors">
        </select>

        <br>
    </div>


    <label> End result </label>
    <div ng-if = "switchColors == 'no'">
        <select ng-model="myEndResult" class="form-control"
            ng-options = "color as color for color in colorSelection" >
        </select>
    </div>
    <div ng-if = "switchColors == 'yes'">
        <select ng-model="myEndResult" class="form-control"
            ng-options = "color as color for color in colorSelectionSwitched">
        </select>
    </div>
    <br>

    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-default">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

The form fields populate as expected, however, when I submit the form, req.query.endResult returns undefined by the server, which means ng-model = "myEndResult" is not submitted. Why is this happening?

Comment: how is your "submit()" function look like?
do you initially initialize "myEndResult" in javascript ?

Comment: @nicost I have added my submit function to the question

Comment: as it seems, "myEndResult" never get's set to a value, and therefore 'null'.
so (assuming you initiate "switchColors" to either "no" or "yes" to actually be able to get into one of the ng-if cases to set 'myEndResult'), you should check myEndResult for null and not emptystring.
Try to change it to the following on the server:

            if (myColor') req.myColor = myColor;
            if (myEndResult) req.myEndResult = myEndResult;

(if you have just the object in the if-clause, you check for 0, null, undefined of the object)

Comment: @nicost I changed it to your suggestion. The browser inspector keeps returning undefined for the radio buttons but actually registers myEndResult, somehow the browser is not sending it to Angular correctly

Answer (score 0):

With radio button use `$parent` like  as-

```
<label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.switchColors" value = "yes" >Yes</input>
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type= "radio" ng-model = "$parent.switchColors" value= "no" >No</input>
    </label>
```

Comment: I was just able to fix this problem actually, there was a typo with my submit function. And it worked with value instead of ng-value. I am curious to why everyone says that ng-value is better because on the official docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D they used value and not ng-value

Comment: ng-value is binding it to a $scope-variable. assuming you have ng-value="yes", it looks for a variable called '$scope.yes' and takes its value. If it's not defined, its obviously null. Having value instead takes the value "yes" as it is.

Answer (score 0):

as it seems, `myEndResult` never get's set to a value, and therefore is `null`.

Assuming you initiate "switchColors" to either "no" or "yes" to actually be able to get into one of the ng-if cases to set 'myEndResult', you should **check `myEndResult` for null and not emptystring**.
Try to change it to the following on the server:

```
if (myColor) req.myColor = myColor;
if (myEndResult) req.myEndResult = myEndResult;
```

If you have just the object in the if-clause, you check for 0, null, undefined of the object.